# Indexing error scanning list

Tags: python, indexing

I apologize ahead of time for the basic nature of this question but I could really use a different set of eyes to see why I'm still getting an `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Here is my code:

```
def longestRun(L):
    counter=1
    ii=0
    counts=[1]
    while ii<=max(range((len(L)))):
        if L[ii] <= L[(ii+1)]:
            counter+=1
            ii+=1
        else:
            ii+=1
            counts.append(counter)
            counter=1
            continue
    counts.sort()
    return counts[-1]
```

It is supposed to count the longest streak of consecutive increases for a list  of integers. I got it working by subtracting 1 from the while statement but then it will not always show the right answer because it won't go through the whole list.

Here is my specific error message:

```
IndexError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-1b4664f2fb31> in <module>()
----> 1 longestRun(L)

C:\Users\james_000\Desktop\longestRun.py in longestRun(L)
      4     counts=[1]
      5     while ii<=max(range((len(L)))):
----> 6             if L[ii] <= L[(ii+1)]:
      7                 counter+=1
      8                 ii+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is `while ii<=max(range((len(L)))):` and then your if statement's condition accesses `L[ii+1]` which runs off the end of the array.

Comment: I tried to change that as stated in my post by subtracting 1 from that statement but it then fails to go through the entire list. Im starting to think there is probably a fundamental error in the code and I should probably just give it another shot from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple math. Let's say `L` is of length 10. That makes the last index 9. `ii` can eventually be 9, thus `ii+1` is going to be out of range.